# CountDownTimer - glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a countdown timer, for every tick I am changing the image in the imageview. It is working fine in sony xperia which runs in icecream sandwich. When I tried the same in another sony xperia which runs on jelly bean, there was some strange error    -   glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502 .

I really don't have any clue on why this is happening.

1. Is this the issue related the change in OS ?
2. How to overcome this issue ?

Thanks in Advance

### LogCat:

```
05-19 22:22:28.218: I/QuizHard(2526): counterPandaImage = 1 millisUntilFinished : 659
05-19 22:22:28.308: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.318: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.338: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.358: I/QuizHard(2526): counterPandaImage = 2 millisUntilFinished : 526
05-19 22:22:28.378: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.388: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.418: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.458: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.488: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.518: I/QuizHard(2526): counterPandaImage = 3 millisUntilFinished : 364
05-19 22:22:28.538: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.558: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.598: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.638: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.668: I/QuizHard(2526): counterPandaImage = 4 millisUntilFinished : 216
05-19 22:22:28.678: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.708: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.748: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.778: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.808: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.838: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.868: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.908: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.938: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.968: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:28.998: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.038: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.078: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.108: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.138: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.168: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.198: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.238: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.268: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.318: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.328: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.358: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.388: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.408: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.438: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.468: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.508: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.538: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.568: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.608: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.638: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.668: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.708: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.738: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.768: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.798: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.838: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.868: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.898: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.928: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.958: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:29.988: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:30.038: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:30.058: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:30.088: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:30.128: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:30.158: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
05-19 22:22:30.198: E/(2526): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
```

Comment: What is your tick time? Maybe you are doing it to fast for this device, and the previous action isn't finished and you already try doing new one.

Comment: pandaTimeCounter = new CountDownTimer(700 , 100)